# Troubleshooting "Undefined offset" error

Tags: php

It's show following error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\evantechbd\secure\content\feature_link_process.php on line 28.

Why it's show the error...? Can anyone tell me... Here is the code:

```
$row = explode("|", $_POST['coun_name']);
$coun_id = $row[1]; // cat_id
$coun_name = $row[0];

if(isset($coun)){
    $errors = array();      
    if(empty($coun))
    $errors[] = 'Country Name require<br>';             
}
```

Comment: Also, please review http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: line - 28 : $coun_id = $row[1]; // cat_id  
$coun_name = $row[0];

Comment: can you do a `print_r($row)` and add the output to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to do something like this, instead:

```
$errors = array();

if( empty($_POST['coun_name']) )
{
  $errors[] = 'Country Name required.';
}
elseif( strpos($_POST['coun_name'], '|') === false )
{
  $errors[] = 'Country Name invalid.';
}
else
{
  list($coun_name, $coun_id) = explode("|", $_POST['coun_name'], 2);
}
```

The first condition checks to make sure the user submitted a value for `$_POST['coun_name']`.  The second condition checks to make sure that the value contains a '|' character.

If both conditions are met, `$coun_name` and `$coun_id` are populated by `explode()`'ing `$_POST['coun_name']` as normal (I dropped in a call to [`list()`](http://php.net/list) for brevity).

Answer (score 1):

```
$row = explode("|", $_POST['coun_name']);
$coun_id = $row[1]; // cat_id
$coun_name = $row[0];
```

if $_POST['coun_name] has no | than $row[1] is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @rauschen. sorry, i don't understand,what is wrong in my code and what should i do?

Comment: I think the problem occurs when $_POST['coun_name'] is emtpy .. nothing is selected.. You already check later if the `coun = $_POST['coun_name'];` is emtpy .. to the explode after the checking..